# What is the correct way to run multiple (500+) cURL commands in a row?

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

I am running cURL commands from a php page to access information from a third-party API. There is maximum rate of 180 requests per minute.

I need to update 10,000+ records.

Here is how I currently have things set up:

1. Connect to my MySQL database and find all records that need to be updated. This returns 10,000+ records.
2. GET needed data from the API using cURL, one by one, and update my database with the new information. Then there is a .5 second pause to make sure I don't exceed the requests per minute maximum.

To make the page run, I have to visit it. For example, I would visit http://example.com/run_curl.php in my browser.

Since there are 10,000+ records, it takes a long time to finish. But I get a 504 Gateway Timeout after the page doesn't finish loading in a few minutes.

So, I have to refresh the page a bunch of times to finish all the updates.

Is there a better way to do this so I don't have to refresh the page 20 times?

Comment: Can't you do it from CLI?

Comment: Browsers/webservers have a timeout that's hard to override. Something like this, it would be better run on the command line that does not have a timeout issue.

Comment: Ok, I will run it on the CLI. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I hadn't even thought of that.

Comment: Can you run look ups in batches? Some APIs allow that. 

You could also limit the number of records returned. I'm assuming that once records are updated, they don't need to be updated again. So do them in blocks of 180 records on a cron job that runs every one or two minutes.

Comment: @liz Yes I can. That would actually be an easy solution for me. Thanks for the idea!